# Remote control for Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Remote control for Autodesk Forge Viewer. Allows to interact with Viewer using Natural Language or Speech Recognition interfaces to perform conversation in chat-like mode.

Currently works fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox due a Speech-To-Text issues.

Feel free to check it on GitHub repository: [viewer-remote](https://github.com/naturalDesign/viewer-remote)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for raising this issue here for all to evaluate and discuss!

You also say: "Probably you could suggest some more places to discuss this with developers?"

Not really. This is probably the best place, and I can think of no other ones. We are trying to concentrate all questions and discussions on Forge related technical issues here on StackOverflow.